# Warning of divide by zero encountered in log2 even after filtering out negative values

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, series

We get the error - "divide by zero encountered in log2"
if the value is less than zero.  I am facing the error even when I exempt the non-positive values using where statement.

```
a = pd.Series([1,0,5,6,8])
np.where(a<=0, 1, np.log2(a))
```

Comment: What are you expecting from this? 'a' must be a positive real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are computing the values that should be substituted when values in `a` are non-positive, `log2` is called and applied to `a`. This doesn't really affect your output though. To suppress this error, you could replace non-positive values with 1 first, and perform `log2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series([1,0,5,6,8])

for digit in a:
    np.where(digit<=0, 1, np.log2(digit))
```

it seems the issue is if you just do

```
np.where(a<=0, 1, np.log2(a))
```

it sees the entire series not as an iteration through a.